# Textbox with required not working

Tags: html, css, forms

I made a form, and I put required in every text box. But for some reason it doesn't work.

If anyone knows a solution for this, please let me know.

```
<form name="mailForm" method="post" action="mail.php" >
                <div class="form">
                    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Naam" id="Naam" value="Naam *" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"  required>
                    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="E-Mail" id="E-Mail" value="E-Mail *" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" required>
                    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" value="Onderwerp *" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" required>
                    <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="Bericht" id="Bericht" value="Bericht *"cols="0" rows="0" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" required>Bericht *</textarea>

                    <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Verstuur" name="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: @Marvin i removed it and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set a default value (`value=""`) and you reset your input elements to that value with your `onblur` listener every time the element is left emtpy. So the browser will always see content.

Remove your listeners and rely on the [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) instead:

```html
<form name="mailForm" method="post" action="mail.php">
  <div class="form">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Naam" id="Naam" placeholder="Naam *" required>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="E-Mail" id="E-Mail" placeholder="E-Mail *" required>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" placeholder="Onderwerp *" required>
    <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="Bericht" id="Bericht" placeholder="Bericht *" cols="0" rows="0" required></textarea>

    <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Verstuur" name="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked! The problem was that i used value instead of placeholder :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because it already has a `value`, so you can change it to `placeholder`

```html
<form name="mailForm" method="post" action="mail.php" >
  <div class="form">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Naam" id="Naam" placeholder="Naam *" required>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="E-Mail" id="E-Mail" placeholder="E-Mail *" required>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" placeholder="Onderwerp *" required>
    <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="Bericht" id="Bericht" placeholder="Bericht *"cols="0" rows="0" required>Bericht *</textarea>

    <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Verstuur" name="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
        <form name="mailForm" method="post" action="mail.php" >
            <div class="form">
                <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Naam" id="Naam" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"  required="required">
                <input class="input-text" type="text" name="E-Mail" id="E-Mail" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" required="required">
                <input class="input-text" type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" required="required">
                <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="Bericht" id="Bericht" value=""cols="0" rows="0" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" required="required">Bericht *</textarea>

                <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Verstuur" name="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
```

See that I changed from `required` to `required="required"`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you HTML declaration is HTML5 else change

```
required
```

to

```
required="required"
```